# Getting Current local Time

Tags: c#, android, datetime, xamarin.android

I have code that is executed in server when a user makes a booking.
That code gets the current universal time.

Now can i change the time according to the time zone. Currently i want to use the time of Australia even though the server is in US.

How can i do it.

My current Code is:

```
booking.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TimeZoneInfo`

```
DateTime hwTime = new DateTime(2007, 02, 01, 08, 00, 00);
try
{
   TimeZoneInfo hwZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time");
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} local time.", 
           hwTime, 
           hwZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(hwTime) ? hwZone.DaylightName : hwZone.StandardName, 
           TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(hwTime, hwZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local));
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Hawaiian Standard Time zone.");
}                           
catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Hawaiian STandard Time zone has been corrupted.");
}
```

but also I recommend to use [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) with a lot of features and supports

Answer (score 1):

I would personally store the date on the server as a UTC regardless of where the booking was made. When you display this booking on a client, simply convert the UTC back to a local time.

Or, if you want to view the time as Australian without actually being in Australia..

```
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
        DateTime UKTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("United Kingdom Time {0}", UKTime);
        DateTime CurrentUTC = UKTime.ToUniversalTime();
        Console.WriteLine("UTC Time {0}", UKTime);
        DateTime OzzieTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(CurrentUTC, tzi);
        Console.WriteLine("Ozzie Time {0}",OzzieTime);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Which produces...

```
United Kingdom Time 31/10/2012 00:30:10
UTC Time 31/10/2012 00:30:10
Ozzie Time 31/10/2012 11:30:10
```